# Failed to request resource with facebook and twitter login oauth

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, laravel-4, oauth-2.0

I have an issue with my Facebook and Twitter login but only in production (I also have a Google login but it works fine in production). When I run it on localhost I can login without problems. When in production I'm getting a *TokenResponseException* exception.

I'm using [artdarek's oauth-4-laravel](https://github.com/artdarek/oauth-4-laravel) but there doesn't seem to be much support in the Issues area.

My code is as follows:.

```
public function loginWithFacebook() {
    // get data from input
    $code = Input::get( 'code' );

    //  $OAuth = new OAuth();
    //  $OAuth::setHttpClient('CurlClient');
    // get fb service
    $fb = OAuth::consumer( 'Facebook','http://fisicloud.com/facebook/' );

    // check if code is valid

    // if code is provided get user data and sign in
    if ( !empty( $code ) ) {
        // This was a callback request from facebook, get the token
        $token = $fb->requestAccessToken( $code );
```

Below is the error I'm seeing. How can I fix this?

[image: "Failed to request resource."]